# Prove that $P(1+i)^n \geq P(1+ni)$

Tags: proof-writing, finance

I'm trying to prove that compound interest $\geq$ simple interest
I am however stuck below:
$F_{compound} \geq F{simple}$ where F is future worth
$P(1+i)^n \geq P(1+ni)$
$(1+i)^n \geq (1+ni)$

I tried using induction but also stuck due to the 2 variables.

Comment: This is known as the Bernoulli's inequality. You can check it out [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

Comment: What is $P$, $i$, $n$, compound interest and simple interest? You should definitely define all these terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the binomial theorem:

$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{x=0}^n \binom{n}{x}\cdot  a^{n-x}\cdot b^x$$

In your case $a=1, b=i$. On the RHS evaluate the first two summands, namely for $x=0$ and $x=1$.